# Xamarin CS1508: The resource identifier `...' has already been used in this assembly

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

Tried to **rebuild** a solution on a Mac using Xamarin. Worked ok a month ago. Now get `CS1508` on 1 of 30 projects.

I updated to Xamarin Studio 6.1.1 after getting the `CS1508`error. Update failed to fix problems. Solution was created on Windows, downloaded from TFS, rebuilt to run under Mono 4.6.1.

Note that I have a relatively new version of
`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.1/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets`, newer than my last successful build. Confirmed resource file in question has been added to compile line from diagnostic output. Tried deleting solution and re-downloading from TFS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the build log from your project?